# When does it count from zero?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a `UITableView` with multiple prototype `cells`. I then have a `NSMutableArray` that stores the `cellID's` so I can retrieve them at `cellForRow...` Here is the code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.cellID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"typeOfGraph", @"graph", @"time", nil];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *currentCellID = [self.cellID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:currentCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"%ld and %lu", (long)indexPath.row, (unsigned long)[self.cellID count]);
    ...
}
```

When I make an `NSLog` of `indexPath.row` and `cellID.count`, for the last `indexPath` I get:

```
indexPath.row = 2
cellID.count  = 3
```

Does it count from zero or not? When it calculates the `indexPath.row`, it seems like it does count from zero, but it doesn't seem like it does at `cellID.count`.

My question is, when and why doesn't it always count from zero?

Comment: It has 3 elements (count of 3) with indexes being 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: I understand it has 3 elements, but doesn't it count from 0?

Comment: Of course it does. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called with index paths that have the rows 0, 1, and 2. These will correspond to the indexes used to access the `cellID` array.

Comment: Why does the index path start from 0, and the `array` start from 1?

Comment: @rmaddy Oh, Sorry for bothering! I get it now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With indexPath.row you are getting the position in the array.

With cellID.count you are getting the number of items in the array.

- Item "1" is at location "0"
- Item "2" is at location "1"
- Item "3" is at location "2"